# Mysql Script to Loop an update

Tags: mysql

IS there a way to loop an update statement in mysql using mysql script. My code shown below

```
UPDATE table_name
SET column_name(REPLACE(column_name,Char(16), '')
```

I want that to loop from 16 to 31. Kindly advice.

I tried creating a script such as the one below

```
DELIMETER $$
CREATE DEFINER  `root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `myupdate`()
 BEGIN
   DECLARE c INT;
   SET c  16;
     WHILE c < 31 DO
       UPDATE table_name
       SET column_name = replace(column_name, char(16), '');
       commit;
         SET c = c + 1;
     END WHILE;
  END
```

Kinda wrong if you ask me but I'm so new here in mysql. Kindly advice sir and Madam and Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using `=` in `SET c 16;`.
I made some changes. Try:

```
DELIMETER $$
CREATE DEFINER  `root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `myupdate`()
 BEGIN
   SET @c = 16;
     WHILE @c < 31 DO
       UPDATE table_name SET column_name = replace(column_name, char(@c), '');
       SET @c = @c + 1;
     END WHILE;
  END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: How CanI use this script sir to run for all columns inside a table not just by column. Somethng like `UPDATE table_name SET (all columns) = raplce((all columns),char(c), '');` In that line

Comment: @Patrick A possible way is to list the columns like this: `UPDATE table_name SET column_name_1 = replace(column_name_1, char(c), ''), column_name_2 =replace(column_name_2, char(c), ''), column_name_3 =replace(column_name_3, char(c), '');`

Comment: My script does not work. :( is there a less stressing way to loop the update script?

Comment: @Patrick I would in a programming language such as PHP. It did not work, but it gave some error in MySQL?

Comment: Nah, I just need some script to run it in mysql itself. Just for studying purposes. It seems that there's more of my hair that needs pulling before I understand this one.

Comment: @Patrick What are the fields that need to change in the script. Tells me that I put the script almost ready and you test again.

Comment: Actually the code is just `UPDATE TABLE SET COLUMN = REPLACE(COLUMN,CHAR(16),'')` And i want to loop it from 16 all the way to 31.

Comment: It does work I know and I feel it. But it seems that I can't get it to work using mysql. :( I think I'm not doing it right.